# asyncio seems to be finishing before HTTP request complete

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, python-asyncio

I am attempting to run many parallel calls to a web service (formatted by a GET querystring) using `asyncio` and the calls all immediately return a value of 0.  The web service is a physics simulation that returns an integer value with how well it performed.  However, I would expect the service to run for approximately 2 minutes and then return the value, however printing out the values from `asyncio` display immediate 0 values.

This code is part of a genetic algorithm (running DEAP), so what I want to do is to have an outer (generational) loop that runs, with each individual (constructed URL) running in parallel and performing the evaluation.  I'm not sure if this has any impact, but it is a Google Cloud Function.  The maximum execution time is set well within the bounds of the expected evaluation time, and the maximum memory is also valid.

Here are my `asyncio` functions, where I'd expect to see some valid integer value if the response returns OK, or -999 if an error was generated:

```
# AsyncIO functions for interacting with Google Cloud Functions
async def fetchCF(indv: str, session: ClientSession, **kwargs) -> str:
  resp = await session.request(method="GET", url=indv, **kwargs)
  resp.raise_for_status()
  html = await resp.text()
  return html

# Dispatch the CFs and return fitness
async def callCF(indv: str, session: ClientSession, **kwargs) -> int:#float:
  try:
    html = await fetchCF(indv=indv, session=session, **kwargs)
  except (
    aiohttp.ClientError,
    aiohttp.http_exceptions.HttpProcessingError,
  ) as e:
    print(indv,e)
    return -9999,
  else:
    return int(html),

# Called via GA
async def evalAsync(pop: set, **kwargs) -> None:
  async with ClientSession(read_timeout=None) as session:
    tasks = []
    for p in pop:
      #print(p)
      indv_url = '%s?seed=%d&x0=%d&y0=%d&x1=%d&y1=%d&x2=%d&y2=%d&x3=%d&y3=%d&emitX=%d&emitY=%d' % \
                 (url,args.seed,int(p[0]),int(p[1]),int(p[2]),int(p[3]),int(p[4]),int(p[5]),int(p[6]),int(p[7]),int(p[8]),int(p[9]))
      tasks.append(
        callCF(indv=indv_url,session=session,**kwargs)
      )
return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

And here is how I call them within the generational loop:

```
for g in generations:
  ...
  fitnesses = asyncio.run(evalAsync(population))
```

For reference, the code works fine with a local physics simulation where I replace the call to `asyncio.run` with a `pool.map` call to my local physics driver.

Comment: I'm no expert in `asyncio`, but a couple of things stand out to me. First, are you sure your `session.request()` and `resp.text()` calls are [awaitable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables)? Might need [`asyncio.create_task()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) or something here. Second, I suspect some of your `async` tags are unnecessary. For instance, do you need one on your `with ClientSession ...` loop? I'm not sure.

Comment: @Engineero: I was following the example here as I'm not wholly comfortable with `asyncio` yet: [Tutorial](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/)

Comment: @Engineero: there are no `async` errors in the code, no.

Comment: Your code *is correct and fine*, provided the last `return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)` line is indented to fall within the `async with .. as session:` context manager block. How are you determining how quickly responses are coming back?

Comment: (And if you are using the *relative time between responses coming back*, then know that your tasks were executed concurrently and the responses coming back in clusters is perfectly normal.

Comment: I've removed the bounty and closed this as per the OP's comment on Stephan's answer: *I just discovered some very odd behavior. I ran my code locally to figure out what an ideal set of values would be. I then ran those values on my cloud function. The first time it ran, I got the correct value. Then, I ran that exact same querystring in a private browsing window and the instant result was 0. Then, I refreshed the prior page (where it ran correctly) and that value is also now 0. To me there is something fishy going on at the Cloud Functions end..*

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Regarding timing, it is visually noticeable.  There is an immediate response whereas I have an explicit program execution time that should be 2 minutes.  Regarding the CF fishiness, it seems something is awry with instancing.  The first invocation runs fine, all subsequent invocations return 0.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code you're showing is just working fine.

For verification, I only used a minimally modified variant of your code with some fixed URLs that only return constant numbers with some delay. Then it works as expected.

Therefore, I assume that the web service may not deliver the result you are expecting for your URLs. For verification, you can for example use one of your URLs with all the parameters and call it from a browser or a wget command line program. Perhaps it does not return the expected numbers?

For the standalone test case, three different URLs are called that return the numbers 40, 41, and 42. On the server side, there is a delay of 1-3 seconds.

Only some minor changes made:

- the `int(html)` statement is checked for a `ValueError, e.g. if the query does not return int
- read_timeout is deprecated, so `aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=5 * 60)` is used instead
- callCF is declared to return one int, so comas are removed to not return a tupel

**Standalone Test Case**

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from aiohttp import ClientSession


async def fetchCF(indv: str, session: ClientSession, **kwargs) -> str:
    resp = await session.request(method="GET", url=indv, **kwargs)
    resp.raise_for_status()
    html = await resp.text()
    return html


# Dispatch the CFs and return fitness
async def callCF(indv: str, session: ClientSession, **kwargs) -> int:
    try:
        html = await fetchCF(indv=indv, session=session, **kwargs)
        result = int(html)
    except (
            aiohttp.ClientError,
            ValueError
    ) as e:
        print(indv, e)
        return -9999
    else:
        return result


# Called via GA
async def evalAsync(pop: set, **kwargs) -> None:
    timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=5 * 60)
    async with ClientSession(timeout=timeout) as session:
        tasks = []
        for indv_url in pop:
            tasks.append(
                callCF(indv=indv_url, session=session, **kwargs)
            )
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    population = {"https://www.software7.biz/tst/number.php",
                  "https://www.software7.biz/tst/number1.php",
                  "https://www.software7.biz/tst/number2.php"}

    fitnesses = asyncio.run(evalAsync(pop=population))
    for fit in fitnesses:
        print(fit)
```

**Result**

[image: result]

**Google Cloud Function**

Since it works with a traditional web server, we can now try a simple test with Google Cloud Functions. The above code works without authentication. But it certainly doesn't hurt to add a simple basic authentication. The server-side Google Cloud Function would then look like this:

```
import time
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth

auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

users = {
    "someUser": "someSecret",
}

@auth.get_password
def get_pw(username):
    if username in users:
        return users.get(username)
    return None

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
@auth.login_required
def compute42(request):
    op1 = request.args.get('op1')
    op2 = request.args.get('op2')
    time.sleep(25) 
    return str(int(op1) + int(op2))
```

It takes two operands, sleeps for 25 seconds and then returns the sum of it.

**Adaption of Python Program**

For this Cloud Function, the calling Python program must be slightly modified:

```
async def evalAsync(pop: set, **kwargs) -> None:
    timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=5 * 60)
    auth = aiohttp.BasicAuth(login='someUser', password='someSecret')
    async with ClientSession(timeout=timeout, auth=auth) as session:
        tasks = []
        for indv_url in pop:
            tasks.append(
                callCF(indv=indv_url, session=session, **kwargs)
            )
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    population = {"https://someserver.cloudfunctions.net/computation42?op1=17&op2=4",
                  "https://someserver.cloudfunctions.net/computation42?op1=11&op2=4700",
                  "https://someserver.cloudfunctions.net/computation42?op1=40&op2=2"}

    fitnesses = asyncio.run(evalAsync(pop=population))
    for fit in fitnesses:
        print(fit)
```

Basically only `aiohttp.BasicAuth` and some GET parameters were added to the URLs.

The output of the Python program to the console is then:

```
21
4711
42
```

Comment: Ok, I just discovered some very odd behavior.  I ran my code locally to figure out what an ideal set of values would be.  I then ran those values on my cloud function.  The first time it ran, I got the correct value.  Then, I ran that exact same querystring in a private browsing window and the instant result was 0.  Then, I refreshed the prior page (where it ran correctly) and that value is also now 0.  To me there is something fishy going on at the Cloud Functions end...

Comment: @the_e: right, which correlates with the code you posted here having no issues whatsoever.